# How to create topics if it does not exists in Kafka dynamically using kafka-python

Tags: python, apache-kafka, kafka-python

I'm fairly new to Python and just getting started with Kafka. I am using the library named [python-kafka](https://kafka-python.readthedocs.io/en/master/apidoc/KafkaAdminClient.html) to communicate with Kafka.
Now I have a requirement that I need to create topics dynamically, however if it does exists, I do not need to create it.

From reading the docs I see that I can use **KafkaAdminClient** to create and delete topics, however I do not find any to check if topic exists.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The KafkaAdminClient does not expose a method to list topics but you can get the list of existing topics by simply querying the cluster metadata from a [KafkaClient](https://kafka-python.readthedocs.io/en/latest/apidoc/KafkaClient.html).

For example, this will print all the topics in the cluster:

```
from kafka.client import KafkaClient

client = KafkaClient(bootstrap_servers='localhost:9092')

future = client.cluster.request_update()
client.poll(future=future)

metadata = client.cluster
print(metadata.topics())
```

Comment: For the newer versions use ```from kafka import KafkaClien``` as the project structure is changed.